# jenkins:Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android, docker, jenkins

I have docker-image of jenkins.

Home directory of jenkins is: `/var/jenkins_home` wich mapped to `/home/user`

So, i install android-sdk wich mapped to:

```
 /home/user/tools/android-sdk/
```

When i install Android plugin to Jenkins and make other things.

I start build and get error:

```
21:16:22 $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/tools/android list target
21:16:23 [android] Using Android SDK: /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk
21:16:23 $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
21:16:26 * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5847 *
21:16:26 * daemon started successfully *
21:16:26 $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
21:16:26 [android] Starting Android emulator
21:16:26 $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/tools/emulator -engine classic -ports 5794,5795 -report-console tcp:5824,max=60 -avd hudson_ru_RU_160_1920x1280_android-25_armeabi-v7a -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window -force-32bit
21:16:26 sh: 1: file: not found
21:16:26 sh: 1: file: not found
21:16:26 WARNING: Cannot decide host bitness because $SHELL is not properly defined; 32 bits assumed.
21:16:26 WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.
21:16:26 PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/var/jenkins_home/.android/avd]!
21:17:31 [android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
21:17:31 [android] Stopping Android emulator
21:17:31 $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
```

I try to change `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` to another directory, but no changes..
Error is about to fail to start Android Emulator... 
I create android emulator manually and then try to start it from Jenkins.

Can you help me to fix this error?

P.S. I think it was docker. I think,that i should copy `/bin/bash` to '/bin/sh'